# PowerShell code to copy files from %temp% folder

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a code in PowerShell that copies all the ".*sv$" located inside the temp directory to a custom folder.

I'll use Task Scheduler to run this code every 15 minutes in order to avoid data loss when you close AutoCAD without saving.

This is the code I've written:

```cs
Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
$tempfolder = $env:temp
$destinazione = "Z:\Autocad temp\"
$tempfolder
(Get-ChildItem -Path $tempfolder -include "*.sv$" -Recurse).Count
Copy-Item -Path $tempfolder\ -Include "*.sv$" -Destination $destinazione
(Get-ChildItem -Path $destinazione -Recurse).Count
```

And this is what I get:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Z:\Autocad temp\salva sv$.ps1
C:\Users\dedil\AppData\Local\Temp
5
1
```

Where 1 file is my ps1 file. So none of the 5 files inside the temp directory has been copied.

Comment: Add `-Recurse` to `Copy-Item`

Comment: Copy-Item -path $tempfolder\ -include "*.sv$" -Destination $destinazione -Recurse


PS C:\Windows\system32> Z:\Autocad temp\salva sv$.ps1
C:\Users\dedil\AppData\Local\Temp
6
1

Comment: Unfortunately nothing gets copied even with the -recurse method:
6 files from source directory, 1 file in destination directory

Comment: DO NOT use `-Include` for just one file pattern. use `-Filter` instead - that runs on the filesystem, the `-Include` and `-Exclude` parameters are processed by the cmdlet, not the filesystem and are there for noticeably slower. [*grin*]

Comment: Wow thanks for the tip! Now it runs but I get event the folder copied. How can I avoid them?

Copy-Item -path $tempfolder\ -filter "*.sv$" -Destination $destinazione -Recurse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe `Get-ChildItem` to it:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $tempfolder -include "*.sv$" -Recurse | Copy-item -Destination $destination
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about that possibility!

Get-ChildItem -Path $tempfolder -filter "*.sv$" -Recurse | Copy-item -Destination $destination

Changing the -include to the -filter makes the job! :)